# Badge Count not visible on most of the Android Devices using Phonegap Plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, github, ionic-framework

I am using (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) plugin to set the Badge count, which uses the **ShortcutBadger**
(https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger) library. Using this plugin I am able to get badge count on most of the Samsung Devices, but I am not able to get the badge count on [for an Instance] Xiomi MI4I. Kindly, let me know, if there is any work around to get the badge count?

***The details are as follows:***

**Expected Behaviour:**

Using

```
push.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(function successCallback(){ 
      console.log('success');}, 
       function errorCallback(){ 
          console.log('error');}, 50);
```

the badge count should work.

**Actual Behaviour:**

Using

```
push.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(function successCallback(){ 
     console.log('success');}, 
     function errorCallback(){ 
        console.log('error');}, 50);
```

**Badge count only works on few Samsung based Android devices** viz.: Samsung Note 3 Neo (Android- 5.1.1), etc

**Reproduce Scenario (including but not limited to):**

After registering the device for push notification, on the event of notification received, I have added:

```
push.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(function successCallback(){ 
 console.log('success');}, 
 function errorCallback(){ 
   console.log('error');}, 50);
```

to set the Badge count.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

```
push.on('registration', (data) => {
//push.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(function successCallback(){ console.log('success');}, function errorCallback(){ console.log('error');}, 50);
console.log("device token ->", data.registrationId);
//TODO - send device token to server
});
push.on('notification', (data) => {
push.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(function successCallback(){ console.log('success');}, function errorCallback(){ console.log('error');}, 50);
console.log('message', data.message);
let self = this;
//if user using app and push notification comes
if (data.additionalData.foreground) {
// if application open, show popup
let confirmAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
title: 'New Notification',
message: data.message,
buttons: [{
text: 'Ignore',
role: 'cancel'
}, {
text: 'View',
handler: () => {
//TODO: Your logic here
self.nav.push(DetailsPage, {message: data.message});
}
}]
});
confirmAlert.present();
} else {
//if user NOT using app and push notification comes
//TODO: Your logic on click of push notification directly
self.nav.push(DetailsPage, {message: data.message});
console.log("Push notification clicked");
}
});
```

**Platform and Version (eg. Android 5.0 or iOS 9.2.1):**

Android-5.0.2, 5.1.1, 6.0, 7.0

**(Android) What device vendor (e.g. Samsung, HTC, Sony...):**

Lenovo(A6000), Samsung(Note 3 Neo), Moto(G 4), Xiomi(MI4I)

**Cordova CLI version and cordova platform version:**

Cordova CLI - 6.4.0

**Cordova Platform Version Android -:**
Installed platforms:
android 6.0.0
Available platforms:
amazon-fireos ~3.6.3 (deprecated)
blackberry10 ~3.8.0
browser ~4.1.0
firefoxos ~3.6.3
webos ~3.7.0
windows ~4.4.0
wp8 ~3.8.2 (deprecated)

**Plugin version:**

Cordova plugin version | grep phonegap-plugin-push -
phonegap-plugin-push 1.8.2 "PushPlugin"

**Sample Code that illustrates the problem:**

```
push.on('registration', (data) => {
//push.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(function successCallback(){ console.log('success');}, function errorCallback(){ console.log('error');}, 50);
console.log("device token ->", data.registrationId);
//TODO - send device token to server
});
push.on('notification', (data) => {
push.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(function successCallback(){ console.log('success');}, function errorCallback(){ console.log('error');}, 50);
console.log('message', data.message);
let self = this;
//if user using app and push notification comes
if (data.additionalData.foreground) {
// if application open, show popup
let confirmAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
title: 'New Notification',
message: data.message,
buttons: [{
text: 'Ignore',
role: 'cancel'
}, {
text: 'View',
handler: () => {
//TODO: Your logic here
self.nav.push(DetailsPage, {message: data.message});
}
}]
});
confirmAlert.present();
} else {
//if user NOT using app and push notification comes
//TODO: Your logic on click of push notification directly
self.nav.push(DetailsPage, {message: data.message});
console.log("Push notification clicked");
}
});
```

Thanks - Sid

Comment: In some mobile like moto, badge not work or not show.

Comment: @DheerubhaiBansal, ShortcutBadger library  (https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger), does not support Motorola based devices- If you are considering Phonegap plugin (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push).

Comment: With 3rd party launchers like N launcher and Nova Launcher with dependency of Tesla badge unread, the badge count can be displayed. But the native feature the launcher has for displaying badge count, can it be solely extracted to be used by our ionic apps.